# Get the related products that share the maximum number of tags

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to get the related products that share the maximum possible number of tags.

For example: 

Prod1 has the following tags: tag1, tag2, tag3

Prod2  has the following tags: tag2, tag4, tag5

Prod3  has the following tags: tag2, tag3, tag5

Prod4  has the following tags: tag6, tag7, tag5

So the most related products to Prod1 are as following

1- Prod3 as they are shared with two tags: tag2 & tag3, 

2- The next related product is Prod2 as they are shared with one tag: tag2

My DB schema like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Videos (VideoID INT PRIMARY KEY,
                     VideoTitle VARCHAR(80));

CREATE TABLE Tags (TagID INT PRIMARY KEY,
                   TagText VARCHAR(20));

CREATE TABLE VideosTags (VideoID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Videos,
                         TagID FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Tags,
                         PRIMARY KEY (VideoId, TagId));
```

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result with your current query that you had tried.

Comment: What does "sharing the maximum possible number of tags" mean, precisely? I can think of multiple ways to interpret this.

Comment: Yogesh Sharma, I could not event have an idea how to do it

Comment: Jeroen Mostert, please check the updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the results say for `VideoID = 1111`, then:

```
select
  videoid, count(*) counter
from VideosTags
where 
  videoid <> 1111
  and
  tagid in (select tagid from VideosTags where videoid = 1111)
group by videoid
order by counter desc
```

This will sort the products with most common tags first.

Comment: The counter in the result are always 1, also 1111 record returns in the result!

Comment: There is `videoid <> 1111` in the statement so it is **impossible** to get 1111 in the results. Did you copy the code as it is?

Comment: Sorry my mistake it does not return 1111, but the counter for all rows are always 1

Comment: Try a different products, or post sample data to check.